# ¿Que significa "// /" dentro de un if que niega una variable?

Tags: bash, condiciones, shell-script

Estoy tratando de entender una funcion creada por >*airmon-ng* pero cuando llego a esta linea condicional:

```
if [ ! "${InterfacePhysical// /}" ]; then 
      InterfacePhysical="$(ls -l "$interface_physical_path" | sed 's/^.*\/\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\)$/\1/')"
fi
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `InterfacePhysical="phy0"`
Lo que no entiendo es:
¿Por que la variable se encierra entre llaves? y ¿cual es la funcionalidad de esos "// /" que estan entre las llaves?
Si alguien me puede hacer entender que es lo que valida esta condicion seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Se está evaluando si la variable, quitando los espacios, está vacía o no.

### Explicación extendida

Hay una mecanismo de Bash llamado [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Podemos invocar este mecanismo utilizando las llaves `${variable}`. Ahora que tenenemos esto, podemos llamar a otros "sub mecanismos" (es término personal) como la sustitución:

```
"${variable/patrón/reemplazo}"
```

Lo cual implica que se va a buscar un patrón en la variable *variable* y se va a reemplazar con el reemplazo (obvio). **Pero, normalmente, sólo se reemplazará el primer patrón encontrado**:

```
$ var1="aEEaaEEaaEEa"; echo "${var1/a/0}"
0EEaaEEaaEEa
```

Y sólo se cambió la primera letra "a" por un cero.

En cambio, si iniciamos el patrón con el caracter `/`, **se cambian todas las coincidencias**:

```
$ var1="aEEaaEEaaEEa"; echo "${var1//a/0}"
0EE00EE00EE0
```

Ahora ya sabemos que en tu caso:

```
${InterfacePhysical// /}
```

En la variable `InterfacePhysical`, el mecanismo busca por todas las coincidencias del patrón de los espacios, luego los elimina. Es decir:

```
$ var1=" a    a    a "; echo "${var1// /}"
aaa
```

Y si lo traducimos a español:

```
"${<De la variable var>//<busco por TODOS los espacios>/<se eliminan>}"
```

De usar tan solo una diagonal `/var/pattern/string`, sólo borraría el primer espacio que encuentre.

Luego de que tenemos una variable sin espacios, se procede a hacer una evaluación sencilla:

```
$ var1="a a"; [ "${var1// /}" ] && echo true || echo false
true

$ var1="  "; [ "${var1// /}" ] && echo true || echo false
false
```

Es decir, estamos evaluando si la variable, quitando los espacios, está vacía.

Y negando la condición:

```
$ var1="a a"; [ ! "${var1// /}" ] && echo true || echo false
false
```

Es decir, sólo entrará en el bloque `if` si la variable está vacía.